# PHP output array into SELECT mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

Need to find array, and then run a MYSQL SELECT where array values are present (or not present).

```
$symbol = "abc";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM around";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
foreach($results as $row) {
$stop = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $row['tip']);
if ($stop ==  $symbol) 
{$sword = $row['tip'];
 }}
```

So we need $sword to serve as an array in the event that there are multiple outputs. After we have that array, we need to run a mysql query that shows only those that have $sword array.

```
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM ms WHERE `big` = '$sword'";
 $result = mysql_query( $query );
```

So then we can do something like:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  echo '"time": "' . $row['time'] . '",'; }
```

Comment: Use mysqli instead of mysql. Just had to say it. I'm compelled. I can't stop myself. I'm trying ... nope, can't stop -- mysql_query is deprecated!

Comment: Peter, that is not an answer to the question. That change will not produce the desired outcome.

Comment: I agree. I put my answer below and my comment in the comment section. :-)

Comment: Hi Teb Theestatebook, I would like some clarification about what you want, Please explain as clearly as possible the end goal of your effort. Preferably take us through the logical steps to get you from the beginning to the end (not in code).
Your first sentence "Need to find array, and then run a MYSQL SELECT where array values are present (or not present)." This doesn't seem to reflect what you are trying to do in your code (it sounds like you want to start with an array but you show building an array from DB data).
Thanks

Comment: I needed array_intersect

Comment: Hope this adds clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226506/php-array-intersect-or-in-array-then-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code, converting $sword to an array and using it in your 2nd query:

```
$symbol = array("abc", "def", "ghi");
$sword = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM around";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
foreach($results as $row) {
    $stop = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $row['tip']);
    if (in_array($stop, $symbol)) {
        $sword[] = $row['tip'];
    }
}
if ($sword) {
    $in = '';
    $sep = '';
    foreach ($sword as $s) {
        $in .= "$sep '$s'";
        $sep = ',';
    }
    /* $in now contains a string like "'123abc123', '12abc12', '1abc1'" */
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM ms WHERE `big` IN ($in)";
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        echo '"time": "' . $row['time'] . '",'; 
    }
}
```

Now I'm going to go wash my hands to get all that mysql_query off me... :-)

Comment: sorry - forgot the end comment

Comment: Peter, I am sorry, $symbol is the array

Comment: Are you saying you want it to work for "def" and "ghi" as well as "abc" for you symbol? And if the $stop value is ANY of those then $sword gets assigned? Did $sword need to be an array at all or is it guaranteed a single value?

Comment: I answered the question you asked originally. If this answers that question feel free to upvote it or mark as the accepted answer. If not hopefully someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I apologize for not clarifying originally. If you could provide assistance further, I would appreciate it. Your assessment on your last comment here is correct.

Comment: The thing is, $symbol is coming from a mysql  foreach($result as $row) {  $symbols [] = $row['youareyou']; }

Comment: Sorry. The question more than trebled on your edit. I was willing to help for the original but you'll need to find someone else for the edited question. Good luck.

Comment: Understood. Can you at least tell me how I can get the output of ArrayArray to actually display the values? Meaning there are two entries that it finds, but instead of showing their value it is just saying ArrayArray.

Comment: https://www.google.al/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=vJAQVar6ApL3yQTd34GYBw#newwindow=1&q=php+display+array

Comment: Take a look at my final edit half an hour ago - you didn't get the in_array() implemented - that may solve your problem.

Comment: please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226506/php-array-intersect-or-in-array-then-mysql