# PHP array_intersect or in_array then MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Need to find if two arrays match, and then where they match pull data from the mysql row in which they match. Should I use

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM around";
 $resultsd = $conn->query($sql);
 foreach($resultsd as $rowd) {}

 if (array_intersect($ar1, $ar2)) {
    $sword[] = $rowd['TIM'];
    }
```

or should I use

```
 if (in_array($ar1, $ar2)) {
       $sword[] = $rowd['TIM'];
   }
```

Getting the arrays like:

```
   $ar1[] = $rowd['nim']; 
   $ar2[] = $rowd['nim'];
```

Then how does one go about pulling the specific row that they match at?

I am seeing that they match, and printing out the array's okay:

```
Array ( [0] => dcbabcbded ) Array ( [0] => fafeafaebee [1] => afabfdefcbb [2] => dcbabcbded
```

But when I trying a echo the mysql data where they match I fail:

```
 Array ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

i would go with sql `IN` clause.

You have an array of customer names: `$a = array('john','rob','paul');`

implode array `$nms = join(',',$a);`

Make sql: `'SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE name IN ('.$nms.')';`

---

do the array intersection first (or what you just have to..) to have an array of needed names.

Comment: I have to see where the two arrays match first, then get the mysql data from only that row. What you have provided will not do such, I do not believe.

Comment: yes you have to prepare array of matches to you tend to gather first, use in_array or intersect

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer is not helpful. It simply restates my question.

Comment: allright Show me both arrays and show desired result. This Just must be simple.

Comment: Getting both arrays with $ar1[] = $rowd['nim']; $ar2[] = $rowd['nim'];

Answer (score 0):

use `$new = array_intersect(Array ( [0] => dcbabcbded ), Array ( [0] => fafeafaebee [1] => afabfdefcbb [2] => dcbabcbded))` : then make valid sql as stated in my answer above.

If u are sure you've allways have array intersenct with one or none values, then make sql just with first array element: `$ar[0]` using sql `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I am sorry. This just is not clear. The arrays are stored as $variables. Also I am having trouble pulling the mysql data from the row that they match at. How is that accomplished?

Comment: no i lost you, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = i have this value` **look up POD an use that** ;) bye